# Flask large project setup and error importing views

Tags: python, flask

I am just starting up my first Flask project and I am trying to set it up as packages so the app can be broken up. My file structure is:

```
project/
   setup.py
   config.py
   requirements.txt
   .gitignore
   appname/
       __init__.py
       view.py
       static/
           stylesheets
       templates/
           html
```

I have followed a number of tutorials and some have used `python setup.py` to run the project and others have used `flask run`. First off, what is the difference?

Now in my **init**.py the code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from appname import views

app = Flask(__name__)
```

My views.py has:

```
from appname import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

So far I have been exclusively trying `flask run` but I get the error:

*AppException: The file/path provided (appname) does not appear to exist*

If I replace the from appname import views with the views code it works fine. So the issues lies with how I am importing but I feel like I have tried every sort of importing format I know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing that I see is an infinite loop of imports:

- `appname` imports `appname.views`, and
- `appname.views` imports `appname`.

You can break the infinite loop of imports like this: in `__init__.py`, remove the import of `views` which is not used:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

To run your application, you must tell Flask where you application is. To do that, you need to export an environment variable, like this:

```
export FLASK_APP=appname/__init__.py

flask run
 * Serving Flask app "appname"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Everything is explained in the [Quick start](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) page of the documentation.

Ooops, I forgot your first question: `python setup.py` is used to run setuptools tasks (like the `make` command with `makefile`). It has nothing to do with Flask. See [Building and Distributing Packages with Setuptools](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#developer-s-guide).

Comment: I was reading somewhere that the infinite loops terminate. So it isn't actually an infinite loop. I will try the rest of the solution though. Edit: at the bottom: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/

Comment: Your right, but in that case you must put the `import appname.views` at the end of the file. Good point.

Comment: It worked, I moved `import view' to the bottom of my __init__.py then did the export FLASK_APP=appname/__init__.py. Before I was just going export FLASK_APP=appname

Answer (score -2):

You're trying to import views whereas your module is called view.py see [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) on python packaging

Comment: Probably a misspelling in the project structure…

Comment: blueprints will probably help solve the problem but maybe @joe doesn't understand the purpose of the project structuring.